# How to get my HTML code into a published webite

Tags: http-status-code-404, html, web-publishing

I feel like this is a simple enough question that it should have already been asked and answered, but I have not seen anything on it in my searches.

I am creating a website for my club at school, and need to publish it/make it live/public, whatever you want to call it. Thusfar it is a simple HMTL-only document, but once I get it up and running I will expand it with CSS and Javascript (as I learn them, haha). So how do I turn this HTML file into a real website? Here is some key info:

- The HMTL code is sitting on my desktop in a file (blablabla.html)
- I have server space allocated for me, provided by the school. No need to find a domain.
- I am familiar with using ssh to visit said server, and I have successively used scp to upload my html file to the server address, but when I navigate to the webpage though Chrome, I get an Object Not Found/404 error.
- I'd like to do this the old fashioned way for now, but if there are any reccomendations for web publishing suites on Ubuntu, they are welcome.

So what exactly do I need to do to make it a working webpage? Is there a specific place I need to put the .html file, a specific name it must have? What am I missing?

P.S. For once I do get it working, how do I obtain/upload some MIDI music to give my website that good old fashioned early 90s feel?

Comment: google on how to publish a website.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, but often you have to rename your html file to [index.html](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index).

Comment: @Wimmel, I did change it to index.html, and it still does not work. 

Also, I would really appreciate an explanation as to why this was downvoted to hell. I do understand this is a very basic question, and even that the answer is out there on the internet (even though I have not been able to clearly find one yet... they all involve using Dreamweaver, acquiring a domain name or some other irrelevant thing). I read the guidelines, I do not see how this is "off topic".

I am not blaming you, but I would like some guidance.

Comment: @AlphaBetaParkingLot You can try to post this question on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. It is not programming related, so it is off topic on this site. So I do not mean your question is wrong or invalid. By the way, I did not downvote it, but possibly it was downvoted by others who don't have enough reputation to close a question.

Answer (score 1):

yes, try to rename it to *index.html* if that file is you home page. 
At what URL are you trying to reach your website? http://example.com/mysite/ ??? or maybe http://example.com/mysite/blahblah.html ??

Comment: I did change it to index.html, and it still does not work. The url is of the form  http://example.com/~mysite/, and I have also tried.  http://example.com/mysite/index.html.

Also, I would really appreciate an explanation as to why this was downvoted to hell. I do understand this is a basic question, and even that the answer is out there on the internet (even though I have not been able to clearly find one yet... they all involve using Dreamweaver or some other Irrelevant thing). I read the guidelines, I do not see how this is "off topic".

I am not blaming you, but I would like some guidance.

Comment: @AlphaBetaParkingLot if it still does not work, do you have more information about the way you upload it? For example does a public_html folder exist, and did you put the file there? Do you know which platform (windows, linux) and software (apache, iis) is used by the webserver? Normally you should have gotten instructions from the owner of the webserver where you have to put the files.